# div height and overflow

Tags: html, css

On this template: [GYM](http://gymguide.mustachethemes.com/template/index.html)

If I add add more text under the welcome title, the form is lowered down and then disappears (class .home has `overflow: hidden`).

If I make it visible then will be over the section under it. What I want is the div's height to be modified depending on the text that I add, to show all the content and then start the other section (w/o a scroll for the `div -> overflow: scroll`)

Thanks!

Comment: please show the code inline in the question

Comment: Let me guess, Is that 403 page you're trying to edit?

Comment: your code please, then we can help you

Comment: The link is not showing the 403 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the form **position:relative;** and the carousel **position:absolute;** (with extra positioning).

This will make sure the height will adjust, but still allow the carousel to flow in the background.

Edit (this is what I used):

```
.home form {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 150px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 90;
}

.carousel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```